# Powershell Scripting on IP address

Tags: powershell

How to reset an IP address on every reboot. Is it possible with powershell to write a script such that the IP address is resetted to dynamic IP address every time a user tries to log in?

Comment: Your question is very vague and contains no actual code so we have no idea what, or how, you are trying to do. You really need to read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) as this will help you figure out what your question is missing and why it's being downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You sure can!

First you would need to find your network adapter via WMI. The one you want to refresh IP adress.

```
$ethernet = Get-WmiObject –Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.IpEnabled }
```

Then you would want to release DHCP ip adress using `ReleaseDHCPLease()` method. Like so:

```
$ethernet.ReleaseDHCPLease()
```

Then you want to renew DHCP ip adress using `RenewDHCPLease()` method. Like so:

```
$ethernet.RenewDHCPLease()
```